# React-Markdown disable parsing of underscore

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm using react-markdown to render markdown strings.

However in my strings, I have underscore to indicate blank words to fill in

> e.g My ____________ is awesome.

However it renders as "< strong >__< /strong >, even when i disable < strong > type, it renders only __ but i want it to be the original __________

Or is there another renderer which can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a hard task with official API. According to my tests, `unwrapDisallowed` doesn't help as it's an option to be even more restrictive (remove the strong markers with content altogether).

And depending on your codebase and the depth of integration of `react-markdown`, selecting another Markdown renderer may be a big task (polished styling, customizations, ...)

You could fork the lib and try to remove the strong parsing, but then you have the burden of building and re-integrating upstream patches as long as you're using the component. A modification that could be merged upstream would be a solution, but I can imagine that such a modification is no easy task, as most maintainers prefer generic solutions (in my experience).

My proposal is a workaround as a compromise:

You could replace all underscores  with something similar looking before assigning the content to `react-markdown`. The parser wouldn't interpret this as "strong" markup. Possible candidate: e.g. `'\uff3f'` (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff3f/index.htm) (caveat: wider than a regular underscore)

Comment: awesome str.replace(/_/g, '\uff3f') alone solve all the problems for now. You are a genius!